# com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /protected-area/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation, filenotfoundexception

I'm developing a web application with jee7 and I would organize my .xhtml files into different folder. I tried to set web.xml and faces-config.xml files but when I click on a button to enter in a folder I have this issue,

```
com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /protected-area/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
```

Problem appear when I want enter in both folder, "protected-area" and "public". 
I hope I was clear, I don't understand because it doesn't work.
Many thanks for your help.

These are my files.

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:head>
    <title>jingsen</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    Select where you want to go:

    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="protected area" action="protected-area"></h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton value="public" action="public"></h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton value="testtest" action="test"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jingsen-realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin Pages</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/protected-area/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <role-name>cassa</role-name>
        <role-name>cameriere</role-name>
        <role-name>cucina</role-name>
        <role-name>bar</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>cameriere</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>cucina</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>bar</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>protected-area</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected-area/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>public</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/public/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>

    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>test</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>prova.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: Are "protected-area" and "public" at the same level as WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Hi! thank you for reply. I placed my folders into WEB-INF instead of into Web Pages and now it works

Comment: Before continuing, please fix a severe mistake: replace `<h:commandButton>` by `<h:button>` if the sole purpose is page-to-page navigation and not submitting of a form. By the way, your `javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES` configuration entry is quite strange. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

be sure that index.xhtml is under webapp folder. if isn't , add sub folders before index.xhtml in welcome tag. for example:

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```